# Remote rendering on the cheap

Tags: rendering, network

Environment is a high school. We have older macs that have no graphics cards, so student animations (Blender 2.74) can easily take 3-5 mins per frame. I managed to procure a decent win7-based server with a decent graphics card.

Is using the win7 machine for rendering as simple as 1) Having the macs save the .blend file to a shared directory, 2) running a cron-like job on the win7 machine that looks for files to render and, 3) launches command line blender (maybe cycles rendering) with additional arguments to output to a different shared directory students can check in the morning?

Added:
Yes, it does work fine, 'server' computer is fast enough. Command line i ended up using is:
blender.exe --background {student .blend file} --render-output C:\BlenderOUT{student filename w/out extension} --render-format QUICKTIME -E CYCLES -x 1 -a

where {xxxx} is specific to the job and C:\BlenderOUT\ is a shared directory students can check for and retrieve their animations.

Comment: It would probably work. I think it should open up the blender file in blender, and then render it from there. That sounds great, but will the computer be able to render a whole classful of animations? Good luck!

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer! If the machine isn't fast enough, i guess we'll find out.